# Twig DateExtension translation

Tags: php, symfony, twig, silex

I try to add translation for Twig DateExtension in my Silex application. Here is what I did for now.

First I added the requested components in my composer.json

```
"twig/twig": "^1.22",  
"twig/extension": "^1.3",  
"symfony/twig-bridge": "^2.7",  
"symfony/translation": "^2.7",  
"symfony/config": "^2.7",  
"symfony/yaml": "^2.7",
```

Then I register services like this:

```
<?php
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => __DIR__.'/../views',
));

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TranslationServiceProvider(), array(
    'locale_fallbacks' => array('en'),
    'locale' => 'fr_FR'
));
$app['translator'] = $app->share($app->extend('translator', function($translator, $app) {
    $translator->addLoader('yaml', new Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\YamlFileLoader());
    $translator->addResource('yaml', __DIR__.'/../src/locales/fr.yml', 'fr_FR');

    return $translator;
}));

$app['twig'] = $app->share($app->extend('twig', function(Twig_Environment $twig, $app) {
    $twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text());
    $twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extensions_Extension_Date($app['translator']));
    return $twig;
}));
```

In my fr.yml I try to put translation like this:

```
diff.ago.day: Il y a %count% jour|Il y a %count% jours
test: converted
```

This configuration seems to be partially working because in my template I have (where foo is a DateTime):

```
{{ foo|time_diff }} - {{ "test"|trans }}
```

The result should be:

```
Il y a 1 jour - converted
```

But it's:

```
diff.ago.day - converted
```

So the first part isn't converted while the second one is.

Where is my mistake ?

Thanks a lot.

EDIT:

I finally found my mistake. After digging into Symfony code, I found they use a special domain for translation: 'date'.
So I add a forth parameter to my ressource loading in order to tell it.

The new loading line is now:

```
$translator->addResource('yaml', __DIR__.'/../src/locales/fr.yml', 'fr_FR', 'date');
```